# Why does \includegraphics fail when using TikZ's externalization?

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, tikz-external, auto-pst-pdf

I'm trying to use `\includegraphics` and the `auto-pst-pdf` package to convert and import an EPS file, but when I enable TikZ's `external` library, `\includegraphics` fails with an error message:

```
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-e
scape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "images/exports/EPSMods-fi
gure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{EPSMods}\input{EPSMods}"' did NOT result in a 
usable output file 'images/exports/EPSMods-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:
.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, t
his is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or somet
hing like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found
 in 'images/exports/EPSMods-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to type
set the picture.
```

When I try to prevent externalization of the offending picture with `tikzexternaldisable`, I get the same result.

Is there a way to use `auto-pst-pdf` and TikZ's `external` library at the same time (and independently of one another)?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=images/exports/]
%\tikzset{external/force remake}   % Uncommenting this generates the error every time

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {root}
    child {node {left}}
    child {node {right}
      child {node {child}}
      child {node {child}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip{}

{\tikzexternaldisable       % Removing this causes the third figure to appear in place of this one
\begin{tikzpicture}         % Shouldn't this picture  behave as it would in the absence of the `external` library?
\psfrag{Z}{$Q=\Sigma_X$}
%\psfragfig{GraphA}         % GraphA is an EPS file being processed by `auto-pst-pdf`; this works
\includegraphics{GraphA}    % This fails, even if wrapped in a node
\end{tikzpicture} 
}

\bigskip{}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {A}
    child {node {B}}
    child {node {C}
      child {node {D}}
      child {node {X}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

```
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
auto-pst-pdf.sty    2009/04/26 v0.6 Wrapper for pst-pdf
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
EPSIncludeBug.w18
 pst-pdf.sty    2008/10/09 v1.1v PS graphics for pdfLaTeX (RN,HjG)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
pstricks.sty    2011/10/31 v0.52 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2012/03/11 v2.27 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2012/03/11 v2.27 `PST-fp' (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 preview.sty    2010/02/14 11.86 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)
   dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
 environ.sty    2008/06/18 v0.2 A new way to define environments
  psfrag.sty    1998/04/11 v3.04 PSfrag (MCG)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
EPSIncludeBug-pics.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
```

Comment: Can you also try using the `\pgfuseimage{himage namei}`? You can check the manual Section 79.3.

Comment: Replacing `\includegraphics` with `\pgfuseimage` fails the same way.

Comment: Can't you convert the image _before_ including in the document using, for example, the `epstopdf` command line tool? And more, which compiler do you use? `latex` or `pdflatex`? I am not sure that the latter is fully compatible with the `psfrag` package

Comment: Have you try this answer <http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59368/14500> ?

Comment: @PolGab: Yes, see the comment, added earlier, in the MWE.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Here, with \includegraphics into a node, your document compile (with TeXLive 2011 and pgf 2.10 or with TeXLive 2012 and pgf 2.10 CVS))... Can you give the result of \listfiles?

Comment: @PolGab: Does it compile when the "force remake" line is uncommented?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes...

Comment: @PolGab: And the message above appears nowhere in the log?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius No error message... See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An EPS file (`test-external.eps`) build by gnuplot:

```
# to make an EPS file
set terminal postscript
set output "test-external.eps"
plot sin(x)
quit
```

Then, a LaTeX file (`tikz-externalize.tex`) with `\includegraphics` and TikZ externalization:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/force remake}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {root}
  child {node {left}}
  child {node {right}
    child {node {child}}
    child {node {child}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

{
  \tikzexternaldisable
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \psfrag{sin(x)}{$y=sin(x)$}%
    \node{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{test-external}};
  \end{tikzpicture} 
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {A}
  child {node {B}}
  child {node {C}
    child {node {D}}
    child {node {X}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To compile:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape tikz-externalize.tex
```

Here, the result:

[image]

Comment: Aha! Note the absence, in your MMWE, of `\tikzexternalize[prefix=images/exports/]`.