# Why is the size of my converted EPS files zero?

Tags: tikz-pgf, auto-pst-pdf

When I use `auto-pst-pdf` to convert an EPS (using `\includegraphics`) inside a TikZ picture, I get a picture with zero size (as near as I can tell) and no picture at all of I try to draw a bounding box around it.

How can I determine the dimensions of my converted EPS files? If I try to draw the bounding box, the resulting imported PDF seems not to be included at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Some text.\bigskip{}\bigskip{}\bigskip{}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[opacity=0](0,0)rectangle(1,1); % This ends up being the full extent of the figure
% The following makes the figure vanish altogether if used without the above line
\draw[green,dotted] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\psfrag{Z}{$G^\beta\leq\Sigma_\zeta$}
\includegraphics{GraphA} % GraphA is an EPS file being processed by `auto-pst-pdf`
%\psfragfig{GraphA}; % Has same effect when above is replaced with this
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell from the documentation, the `\psfragfig` command is needed.

Comment: Try top put \includegraphics inside of a node...

Comment: @egreg: Switching to `\psfragfig` has the same result.

Comment: @PolGab: That works. Is there any drawback to doing that?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Please, show the code.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius No drawback! This is the only way to correctly include an external graphic into a tikzpicture.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius `psfragfig` is not required to use \includegraphics...

Comment: @egreg: Just replace the `includegraphics` line with `\psfragfig{GraphA};`. See above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to correctly include an external graphic into a tikzpicture is to use `\includegraphics` into a node.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{\includegraphics{external-graphic-file}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the confusion. I ended up confusing your comments with those about using the suggestion to use `psfragfig` instead.

Comment: Technically, `\includegraphics` is not the only way to correctly include an external graphic into a tikzpicture, PGF has its own image inclusion mechanism (`\pgfdeclareimage`). However, from the manual: "To be quite frank, LATEX's `\includegraphics` is designed better than pgf's image mechanism. For this
reason, I recommend that you use the standard image inclusion mechanism of your format. Thus, LATEX
users are encouraged to use `\includegraphics` to include images."

Answer (score 2):

With `testfig.eps` from the documentation of `psfrag`, this works on my machine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Some text.\bigskip{}\bigskip{}\bigskip{}

\psfragfig{testfig}[\psfrag{gA}{$G^\beta\leq\Sigma_\zeta$}]

\end{document}
```

Of course, the problem of where to put a graphic file in a `tikzpicture` is completely different.